# Xampp server issue: localhost/app_folder giving error 'connection reset'

Tags: xampp

Good morning!

My Xampp has been working fine till a few days ago.

1. i can access localhost/phpmyadmin - i see my db/tables all intact!
2. BUT i cant access localhost/ like i used to. it says connection reset.
3. when i try to access my application thru 127.0.0.1/ the site is not displayed as it is supposed to. images are missing and formatting is out. but i do know my php scripts are working since the menus are being correctly displayed and i am able to log in.
4. i dont use skype but i do have teamviewer and mu torrent

any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had the *connection reset* problem but I fixed it out by:

1. Disconnection from my WiFi
2. Uninstalling and re-installing the XamppServer
3. Checking if phpMyAdmin works (it did in my case)
4. Re-connecting to WiFi and enjoying the internet :)

Hope it might help